# BigQuery CLI: load commands stays pending

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I have a csv file on my computer. I would like to load this CSV file into a BigQuery table. 
I'm using the following command from a terminal:

```
bq load --apilog=./logs --field_delimiter=$(printf ';') --skip_leading_rows=1 --autodetect dataset1.table1 mycsvfile.csv myschema.json
```

The command in my terminal doesn't give any output. In the GCP interface, I see no job being created, which makes me think the request doesn't even reach GCP. 
In the logs file (from the --apilog parameter) I get informations about the request being made, and it ends with this:

```
INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/jobs?uploadType=resumable&alt=json
```

and that's it. No matter how long I wait, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing --autodetect with myschema.json, something like the following shoud work:

```
bq load --apilog=logs \
--source_format=CSV \
--field_delimiter=';' \
--skip_leading_rows=1 \
--autodetect \
dataset.table \
mycsvfile.csv
```

If you continue having issues, please post the content of the apilog, the line you shared doesn't seem to be an error. There should be more than one line and normally contains the error in a json structure, for instance:

```
"reason": "invalid",
      "message": "Provided Schema does not match Table project:dataset.table. Field users is missing in new schema"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using

> --apilog=./logs

I did not find this in the [**bq load** documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table), please clarify.

Based on that, maybe the **bq load** command could be the issue, you can try with something like:

```
bq load \
--autodetect  \
--source_format=CSV \
--skip_leading_rows= 1  \
--field_delimiter=';'
dataset1.table1 \
gs://mybucket/mycsvfile.csv \
./myschema.json
```

If it fails, please check your [job list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#listing_jobs_in_a_project) to get the job created, then use [bq show](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs) to view the information about that job, there you should find an error messag which can help you to determine the cause of the issue.